# MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error collection with no unique field in schema

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, unique

I'm setting up a simple blog form with title, content, and `json base64` image data to pass to a local MongoDB server. This is my post route:

```
router.post('/:userName/posts/new', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    let parsedImage = req.body.file != null && req.body.file != '' ? JSON.parse(req.body.file).data : ''

    const newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        imageJson: parsedImage
    })

    try {
        await newPost.save()
        res.redirect("/account")
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.redirect("/home")
    }
})
```

And this is my schema model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imageJson: {
 

           type: String
        }
});
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

no `unique: true` as you can see. The first time I tried running this, it ran perfectly, redirecting directly to the /account page, as intended in the try catch block. But, on a second attempt, using a different image, different content, and different title, it threw this error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: fullstacksus.posts index: userName_1 dup key: { userName: null }
```

I have no idea what's going on since userName is a database name used in my user account `route`, but not in my post-making `route`. Why is it showing up again? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What does `db.posts.getIndexes()` show ?

Comment: It shows: `[ ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MongoDB there is a unique index on `{userName: 1}`.  Since your schema does not have a userName field, it is missing, i.e. null, in every document, so the index rejects it.

Use the mongo shell to connect and drop the index.

Comment: How do I drop the index? I don't need the unique parameter on the userName